# Jest mock function ignoring passed in values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a super simple test that simply refuses to see the values I'm passing in:

component in test: `const shallow = (props = {}) => shallow(<ParagraphComponent {...props} />);`

The test:

```
it('Should fire onChange', () => {
  const props = {
    context: context.paragraphStyle.style,
    onChange: jest.fn()
  };
  const instance = shallow(props);
  const paragraphInput = instance.find('paragraphInput.fontsize');
  paragraphInput.prop('onChange')(undefined, { unit: "px" value: '123' });
  paragraphInput.prop('onBlur')(); // required to fire the onChange
  expect(props.onChange).toBeCalledWith('font.size', { unit: 'px', value: 123 });
});
```

The test fails with:

> Expected mock function to have been called with:
>             {"unit": "px", "value": 123}
>           as argument 2, but it was called with
>             {"unit": "", "value": ""}.

How on earth can that function be called, but with empty values even though I'm passing in actual values?!?

I've tried passing in `{ target: { value: 123 }}`, I've tried using `act()`, I tried passing the values into `onBlur` nothing works.

Comment: What is this `shallow` function with the `shallow(props)` call? Did you mean `createShallow(props)`? Because if this is the enzyme `shallow` call, the arguments are incorrect.

Comment: I think we'll also need to see `ParagraphComponent` to know exactly what the `onChange` function of `paragraphInput.fontsize` does.

Comment: @Jacob yes it's a shallow wrapper, just copied and pasted wrong. what argument is incorrect?

Comment: I have other tests that look exactly the same and pass.